# jquery tolls list with overlay & scrollable list .. issues

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, image-gallery

hi there i'm relatively new to jquery, but i wanted to see if anyone could provide me with any insight on this.

what i've got here is an autoscrolling list, with overlay functionality..

http://www.freestylemovement.com/secret/3.html

what i'm trying to achieve is a scrollable function like in this example, except i like using the list format .. (see hyperlink on attached form, i'm only allowed to post 1 link)

so i've been messing around with this snippet,

$(function() {
    $("#chained img[rel]").overlay({effect: 'apple', expose: '#00ff00'
                                      }) ;
    // scrollable inside the box. Its API is assigned to the "images" variable
    var list = $("ul.items li ").scrollable({size: 1, api:true});
});

but i can't seem to get it working .. i would really appreciate some feedback and help.. thanks in advance!

Comment: I've given you links to some examples of image gallery's like the one you are trying to create that are built from an unordered list.  If you want help debugging your current code you'll need to edit your answer to format the code and provide additional info about the error or failure you are trying to correct.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview) is an example of a jQuery gallery plugin that's built of an unordered list. If you google [jQuery gallery](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20gallery&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&hs=qQS&tbo=1&output=search&tbs=ww:1) you'll find lots of other gallery plugins built similarly.